# Why are simultaneously executing tasks failing and causing Ignite to freeze?

Tags: python-3.x, ignite

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 
Apache Ignite: 2.8.1

Other info:
Flask Application - for API endpoints
pyignite - as thin client for Apache Ignite

Data Loaded: 
5 tables: 
A: 10 million records 
B: 37.5 million records 
C: 10 million records 
D: 25.3 million records 
E: 5.5 million records

Total taking up 29GB of space in Ignite Persistence.

I'm performing two simple SQL queries: 
Query 1:

```sql
    SELECT  SUM(TABLE_B.ID) AS num_people, TABLE_B.PRODUCT, TABLE_C.CITY
    JOIN TABLE_C 
    ON TABLE_B.ID = TABLE_C.ID
    GROUP BY TABLE_B.PRODUCT, TABLE_C.CITY
    ORDER BY num_people DESC
    LIMIT 1000
```

Query 2:

```sql
    SELECT  SUM(TABLE_A.ID) AS num_people, TABLE_C.CITY
    JOIN TABLE_C 
    ON TABLE_A.ID = TABLE_C.ID
    GROUP BY TABLE_C.CITY
    ORDER BY num_people DESC
    LIMIT 1000
```

I'm running Apache Ignite in a docker container.

This is the configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) ...
-->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <!--
        Alter configuration below as needed.
    -->
    <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <!-- Enabling Apache Ignite Persistent Store. -->
        <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                        <!-- Setting the size of the default region to 48GB. -->
                        <property name="maxSize" value="#{48L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                        <!-- Set the page size to 4 KB -->
                        <property name="pageSize" value="#{4 * 1024}"/>
                        <!-- Enable Native Persistence - required for Authentication -->
                        <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <!-- Enabling authentication. -->
        <property name="authenticationEnabled" value="true"/>

        <!-- Enabling node discovery for Ignite Visor. -->
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <value>ignite:47500</value>
                                <value>ignite:47501</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="communicationSpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
                <property name="sharedMemoryPort" value="-1"/>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <!-- Configure internal thread pool. -->
        <!-- <property name="publicThreadPoolSize" value="32"/>-->

        <!-- Configure system thread pool. -->
        <!--        <property name="systemThreadPoolSize" value="32"/>-->

        <!-- Configure query thread pool. -->
        <!-- <property name="queryThreadPoolSize" value="32"/>-->

        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <list>
                <bean abstract="true" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration"
                      id="cache-template-bean">
                    <!-- when you create a template via XML configuration, you must add an asterisk to
                    the name of the template -->
                    <property name="name" value="tbl_pll*"/>
                    <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
                    <property name="backups" value="1"/>
                    <property name="queryParallelism" value="32"/>
                    <!-- Other cache parameters -->
                </bean>
                <bean abstract="true" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration"
                      id="cache-template-bean">
                    <!-- when you create a template via XML configuration, you must add an asterisk to
                    the name of the template -->
                    <property name="name" value="tbl_hf_pll*"/>
                    <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
                    <property name="backups" value="1"/>
                    <property name="queryParallelism" value="16"/>
                    <!-- Other cache parameters -->
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="failoverSpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.failover.always.AlwaysFailoverSpi">
                <property name="maximumFailoverAttempts" value="2"/>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <!-- Execute one job at a time. -->
        <property name="collisionSpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.collision.fifoqueue.FifoQueueCollisionSpi">

                <property name="parallelJobsNumber" value="1"/>
            </bean>
        </property>

    </bean>
</beans>
```

When I run two SQL queries simultaneously, both of them freeze and the second query always throws a similar error. Sometimes it's Unknown type code: `b' '` and this time it was:

```
app_1  | ERROR:app:Unknown type code: `b'm'`
app_1  | DEBUG:app:Traceback (most recent call last):
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyignite/datatypes/internal.py", line 275, in parse
app_1  |     data_class = tc_map(type_code)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyignite/datatypes/internal.py", line 108, in tc_map
app_1  |     return _memo_map[key]
app_1  | KeyError: b'm'
app_1  | 
app_1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
app_1  | 
app_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
app_1  |   File "/app/analytics/views.py", line 832, in post
app_1  |     ignore_data_limit=ignore_data_limit
app_1  |   File "/app/analytics/apply_rules.py", line 769, in create_view_ignite
app_1  |     dataset_source_details=dataset_source_details)
app_1  |   File "/app/analytics/apply_rules.py", line 685, in apply_rules_ignite
app_1  |     explain = client.sql('EXPLAIN ' + QUERY)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyignite/client.py", line 401, in sql
app_1  |     max_rows, timeout,
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyignite/api/sql.py", line 379, in sql_fields
app_1  |     response_class, recv_buffer = response_struct.parse(connection)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyignite/queries/__init__.py", line 146, in parse
app_1  |     field_class, field_buffer = AnyDataObject.parse(client)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyignite/datatypes/internal.py", line 277, in parse
app_1  |     raise ParseError('Unknown type code: `{}`'.format(type_code))
app_1  | pyignite.exceptions.ParseError: Unknown type code: `b'm'`
```

Ignite Logs:

```
ignite_1              | [10:29:31,529][WARNING][query-#176][IgniteH2Indexing] Long running query is finished [time=6230ms, type=MAP, distributedJoin=false, enforceJoinOrder=true, lazy=false, schema=PUBLIC, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=a3f4gthv, consistentId=a4deb8, addrs=ArrayList [127.0.0.1, 172.19.0.5], sockAddrs=HashSet [/127.0.0.1:47500, 97ba4d812948/172.19.0.5:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1603362363483, loc=true, ver=2.8.1#20200521-sha1:86422096, isClient=false], reqId=6, segment=31, sql='SELECT
ignite_1              | __Z0.ID __C0_0,
ignite_1              | __Z1.CITY __C0_1
ignite_1              | FROM PUBLIC.TABLE_C __Z1 
ignite_1              |  INNER JOIN PUBLIC.TABLE_A __Z0 
ignite_1              |  ON TRUE
ignite_1              | WHERE __Z0.ID = __Z1.ID', plan=SELECT
ignite_1              |     __Z0.ID AS __C0_0,
ignite_1              |     __Z1.CITY AS __C0_1
ignite_1              | FROM PUBLIC.TABLE_C __Z1
ignite_1              |     /* PUBLIC."IDX_TABLE_C_proxy" */
ignite_1              | INNER JOIN PUBLIC.TABLE_A __Z0
ignite_1              |     /* PUBLIC."_key_PK_proxy": ID = __Z1.ID */
ignite_1              |     ON 1=1
ignite_1              | WHERE __Z0.ID = __Z1.ID]
ignite_1              | [10:29:34,890][WARNING][long-qry-#89][LongRunningQueryManager] Query execution is too long [time=3363ms, type=REDUCE, distributedJoin=false, enforceJoinOrder=false, lazy=false, schema=PUBLIC, reqId=6, sql='SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `TABLE_A`.`id`) `num_people`,`TABLE_C`.`city` FROM `TABLE_A` JOIN `TABLE_C` ON `TABLE_A`.`id`=`TABLE_C`.`id` GROUP BY `TABLE_C`.`city` ORDER BY `num_people` DESC LIMIT 10000]
ignite_1              | [10:29:35,923][WARNING][client-connector-#211][IgniteH2Indexing] Long running query is finished [time=4400ms, type=REDUCE, distributedJoin=false, enforceJoinOrder=false, lazy=false, schema=PUBLIC, reqId=6, sql='SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `TABLE_A`.`id`) `num_people`,`TABLE_C`.`city` FROM `TABLE_A` JOIN `TABLE_C` ON `TABLE_A`.`id`=`TABLE_C`.`id` GROUP BY `TABLE_C`.`city` ORDER BY `num_people` DESC LIMIT 10000]
ignite_1              | [10:30:03,730][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#71][IgniteKernal] 
ignite_1              | Metrics for local node (to disable set 'metricsLogFrequency' to 0)
ignite_1              |     ^-- Node [id=a3f4gthv, uptime=00:04:00.021]
ignite_1              |     ^-- H/N/C [hosts=1, nodes=1, CPUs=32]
ignite_1              |     ^-- CPU [cur=0.03%, avg=7.18%, GC=0%]
ignite_1              |     ^-- PageMemory [pages=3141162]
ignite_1              |     ^-- Heap [used=5288MB, free=67.72%, comm=16384MB]
ignite_1              |     ^-- Off-heap [used=12413MB, free=74.9%, comm=49352MB]
ignite_1              |     ^--   sysMemPlc region [used=0MB, free=99.99%, comm=100MB]
ignite_1              |     ^--   default region [used=12413MB, free=74.74%, comm=49152MB]
ignite_1              |     ^--   metastoreMemPlc region [used=0MB, free=99.92%, comm=0MB]
ignite_1              |     ^--   TxLog region [used=0MB, free=100%, comm=100MB]
ignite_1              |     ^-- Ignite persistence [used=29178MB]
ignite_1              |     ^--   sysMemPlc region [used=0MB]
ignite_1              |     ^--   default region [used=29177MB]
ignite_1              |     ^--   metastoreMemPlc region [used=0MB]
ignite_1              |     ^--   TxLog region [used=0MB]
ignite_1              |     ^-- Outbound messages queue [size=0]
ignite_1              |     ^-- Public thread pool [active=0, idle=0, qSize=0]
ignite_1              |     ^-- System thread pool [active=0, idle=5, qSize=0]
ignite_1              | [10:31:03,733][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#71][IgniteKernal]
```

After this, the Ignite Metrics keep coming and the node never returns any output or accepts new tasks. No JVM pauses were logged.

What am I doing wrong and why is Ignite freezing and not responding if simultaneous queries are run?

The queries run properly if you run them one at a time.

PS:
I have read vast amounts of Ignite documentation and troubleshooting on Nabble forums.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue! (Was making a silly mistake)

I was using a python thin client to connect to Ignite and instead of creating a new client for every query, I was reusing a single global client.

I think this is what was happening:
Since the client was running a second query after sending one query for execution, the output of the first query was not being retrieved. This blocked Ignite from running the second query and from retrieving the output for the first one.

If someone with more knowledge on Ignite can correct me or tell me whether I'm right, that would be appreciated.

Comment: You are right @anurags, I am facing the same problem with cache, using multiprocessing and singleton pattern, It's hard to get run two functions at the same time, They are blocking each other.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible that you are running out of heap. With that query, especially if you don't have correct indexes, you're going to use a lot of heap, and when you run out, Java will virtually freeze trying to reclaim more memory in the loop.

What indexes do you have? Also, what does "order by column1" mean to you if you're selecting sum(column1)?

Can you show logs from the Ignite node(s)? I would especially look for "JVM pause" messages.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please take a look. If I should share any other logs do let me know. 
There was no JVM pause messages, the joins are taking place using the Off-Heap as far as I'm aware and the heap memory is not being exceeded.

Comment: Yes, I think you have figured it out. You can't re-use client until you read all results and close the result set.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had actually misunderstood someone else's answer and used a single thin client when I think they meant a single Ignite client.